# Passing databasename to SQL query in webmatrix/razor

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, razor

I have a form built in webmatrix that will be updating data within a user specified database.

I would like the user to insert their DB name into the form, and have the `Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString");` open based on the users submission.

if not possible, is there a way to simply include the user specified DB name within the SQL query below within webmatrix?  Sample of what I have below:

```
 var db = Database.Open("SQLServerConnectionString");
 var selectQueryString = "SELECT donor_id,first_name,last_name FROM SUPPORT.dpo.dp WHERE donor_id=@0";
```

I would like the static "SUPPORT" database in the FROM clause to be updated dynamically based on user input. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you using .mdf files or actual database connection strings? If connection strings you can use the `OpenConnectionString` method and pass a custom connection string instead of using whats in the web.config.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569301(v=VS.99).aspx

Something like this would probably work:

```
@{ 
    var databaseName = Request["databaseName"]; //load from request
    var connectionString = string.Format("Data Source=.\\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog={0};Integrated Security=True", databaseName);
    var providerName = "System.Data.SqlClient"; 
    var db = Database.OpenConnectionString(connectionString, providerName); 
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Product ORDER BY Name"; 
}
```

You can just drop the *SUPPORT.* prefix as its not necessary for the `select` statement.

Comment: Updated my answer, see the **string.Format** call

Comment: Thanks @PaulT, that worked great.  I thought I would need @0 but {0} is what I needed.  There difference is still a bit foggy to me.

Comment: @0 is a placeholder for a parameter value in a SQL query. {0} is (mostly) a placeholder for a dynamic value in a string.Format method call.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  That helps a lot.